# How to merge duplicate columns with different values in pandas before exporting to SQL?

Tags: python, pandas

I have such script

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2

db_host = "localhost"
db_port = "5432"
db_name = "postgres"
db_user = "postgres"
db_password = "postgres"

connection_string = f"postgresql://{db_user}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}"

engine = create_engine(connection_string)

csv_file = "selected_data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)

df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\n', '', regex=True)

duplicated_columns = df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep="first")]
print(duplicated_columns)

df = df.drop(columns=duplicated_columns)
# df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(x) if (x.dtypes == object).all() else x.sum())

table_name = "public.selected_data"  

df.to_sql(table_name, engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

engine.dispose()
```

My problem is that in the file, there are several columns with the same name but they hold different values. Currently, in my script, it is written to delete all duplicate columns. However, I need to merge them into one column along with their values. But I can't figure out how to do it.

```
Original df:
   A  B  C  C etc.
0  1  2  0  2
1  1  3  0  3
2  4  6  1  0
```

And I want to get in result this:

```
Result df: 
Out:
   A  B  C  etc.
0  1  2  2
1  1  3  3
2  4  6  1
```

Comment: Did you try to define column names as a list like this: `df.columns=["a","b","c"]`?

Comment: @Bushmaster there are more than 100 columns, I can't define them manually.

Comment: It's not difficult, so create an example and generate the desired output accordingly. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) (e.g., the output of `df.head().to_dict('tight')`) and the matching expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
duplicate_columns = list(df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep="first")])
for i in duplicate_columns:
    df["main_col_" + i] = df[[i]].sum(axis=1)
    df = df.drop([i],axis=1).rename(columns={"main_col_" + i:i})
```

**Test**:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[400,400],[1,2],[100,200],[1,2],[10,10]]).T
df.columns = ["a","a","b","c","c"]

'''
     a  a    b  c   c
0  400  1  100  1  10
1  400  2  200  2  10
'''
```

Then:

```
duplicate_columns = list(df.columns[df.columns.duplicated(keep="first")]) #['a', 'c']
for i in duplicate_columns:
    df["main_col_" + i] = df[[i]].sum(axis=1)
    df = df.drop([i],axis=1).rename(columns={"main_col_" + i:i})
```

**Out**:

```
     b    a   c
0  100  401  11
1  200  402  12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom function with rename columns names by `dtypes`:

```
#join by , if object else sum
def f(x):
    try:
        return x.agg(', '.join, axis=1)
    except TypeError:
        return x.sum(axis=1)

out = df.groupby([df.columns, df.dtypes], axis=1).apply(f)

#rename columns names if duplicated has numeric and object columns
m1 = out.columns.get_level_values(0).duplicated(keep=False)
m2 = out.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'object'

out = out.droplevel(1, axis=1)
out.columns += np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2], ['_num','_str'], '')
```